# Add via fetch to a card the comment, rate and elementId data and display them on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to retrieve comment, elementId, and rate data from a fetch to display under the card when I click on it. From the fetch I get this

```
{_id: '6405e90402cacd00132f1b21', comment: 'test comment', rate: 3, elementId: '6405c9f102cacd00132f1a2e', author: 'antoniovallerga85@gmail.com', …}
author
: 
"antoniovallerga85@gmail.com"
comment
: 
"test comment"
createdAt
: 
"2023-03-06T13:22:12.139Z"
elementId
: 
"6405c9f102cacd00132f1a2e"
rate
: 
3
updatedAt
: 
"2023-03-06T13:22:12.139Z"
__v
: 
0
_id
: 
"6405e90402cacd00132f1b21"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

This is all the code for the BookCard and the CommentArea:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CommentArea from '../commentArea/CommentArea';

const BookCard = ({ title, category, btn, img }) => {
  // 1. Creiamo uno stato locale "isSelected" per tenere traccia dello stato selezionato della card.
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);

  // 2. Questa funzione gestisce il clic sulla card. Quando la card viene cliccata, inverte lo stato "isSelected".
  const handleCardClick = () => {
    setIsSelected(!isSelected);
  };

  // 3. Restituisci la componente Card che rappresenta un singolo libro.
  return (
    <Card
      // 4. Applichiamo uno stile condizionale alla card in base allo stato "isSelected".
      style={{
        width: '18rem',
        border: isSelected ? '5px solid red' : 'none'
      }}
      // 5. Aggiungiamo un gestore di eventi "onClick" alla card, in modo che venga chiamato quando la card viene cliccata.
      onClick={handleCardClick}
    >
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={img} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>{category}</Card.Text>
        {/* Ho importato da CommentArea il componente*/}
        <CommentArea selected={isSelected} />
        <Button variant="primary">{btn}</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default BookCard;
```

CommentArea:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const CommentArea = ({ selected }) => {
    //useState in reviews è un array perchè dovra renderizzare i diversi commenti che verranno inseriti
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setErrors] = useState(null)

    const getCommentFromApi = async () => {
        setLoading(true);

        try {
            const token = 'CENSORED'; // Sostituisci con il tuo token effettivo
            const headers = {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            };

            const response = await fetch('https://striveschool-api.herokuapp.com/api/comments/6405c9f102cacd00132f1a2e', {
                headers,
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                setReviews(data);
                console.log(data);
            } 

        } catch (error) {
            // Gestisci qui gli errori di rete o altri errori
            console.error('Errore durante la chiamata API:', error);
            setErrors(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }

    }


    useEffect(() => {
        if (selected)
        getCommentFromApi()

        return () => {
            //logica che viene eseguita quando il componente viene smontato
        }

    }, [selected])


    return (
        // Il secondo selected serve per richiamare quello nelle parentesi.
        // Selected && è una sintassi classica per condizionare il rendering del componente da true a false e viceversa
        selected && (
            <div>
                <h2>Commenti</h2>
                {loading && <p>Caricamento in corso...</p>}
                {error && <p>Si è verificato un errore durante il recupero dei commenti.</p>}
                {/* Aggiungi qui la visualizzazione dei commenti */}
                <ul>
                    {reviews.map((review) => (
                        <div key={review._id}>
                            <p>Comment: {review.comment}</p>
                            <p>Rate: {review.rate}</p>
                            <p>Element ID: {review.elementId}</p>
                        </div>
                        
                    ))}
                   
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    );
};

export default CommentArea;
```

The data from the fetch come in.

[image: ERROR]

But from what I can see there is a problem in the last part of the code.

```
  return (
        // Il secondo selected serve per richiamare quello nelle parentesi.
        // Selected && è una sintassi classica per condizionare il rendering del componente da true a false e viceversa
        selected && (
            <div>
                <h2>Commenti</h2>
                {loading && <p>Caricamento in corso...</p>}
                {error && <p>Si è verificato un errore durante il recupero dei commenti.</p>}
                {/* Aggiungi qui la visualizzazione dei commenti */}
                <ul>
                    {reviews.map((review) => (
                        <div key={review._id}>
                            <p>Comment: {review.comment}</p>
                            <p>Rate: {review.rate}</p>
                            <p>Element ID: {review.elementId}</p>
                        </div>

                    ))}

                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    );
};
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.map()` is a function on an array.  Your data is not an array.  Did you want to put it in an array?  Or, since there's only one record, did you want to not use an array at all and just display that record?  Or something else?

Comment: first of all, thank you for making yourself available, there's only one record there because as you see from the endpoint I made the call to only one string of data, so for just one I don't need to put it in an array, just display the data under the card when I click on it.
if you can also tell me how to do it if I wanted to do it with multiple records, it would solve a problem that will definitely come up, thank you very much

Comment: @MikeYoulend The point @David is making is `map` is only available in an Array, not Object. In other words, `[].map()` is okay, but `{}.map()` throws error. You have to store the `reviews` inside an Array for the `map` to work.

Comment: @MikeYoulend: Are you saying that the data *could be* an array, but deliberately isn't in this one example?  It's not clear what the goal is then.  Does this API return different data structures depending on how it's queried?  (If so, that's... not great.  Data structure consistency is important for an API.)  Do you specifically want to use an object (one record) or an array (zero or more records)?

Comment: @David I want to use zero or more records, excuse me if I can't explain myself well, I have been using react very recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data shown is not an array, it's an object.  And `.map()` is used to iterate over an array.  In comments on the question above it sounds like the data *might be* an array, or *might be* a single object.  If there's any way to make the structure *consistent* then that would be ideal.  But, failing that, you can test if something is an array before using it as one.  For example:

```
const renderedReviews = Array.isArray(reviews) ? reviews : [reviews];
```

If you do this just before the `return` for the component then just use `renderedReviews.map()` instead of `reviews.map()`.  Either way you're still using the `reviews` state value, just conditionally wrapping it in an array if it isn't already one.